# Loop over files in several sub directories

Tags: python, subdirectory

I need to be able to go over every .txt file in 14 different subfolders of a folder, which means being able to open and manipulate the texts, since the rest of my work is nlp related.

The subdirectories are in a subdirectory `USEcorpus` of itsit'sown within a parent folder `in` in my workspace.

Here is my code:

```
# defining path
data_dir = os.path.join("in", "USEcorpus")

# for every directory in data_dir
for dir in (os.listdir(data_dir)):
    # make the subdirectory path string
    subdir = os.path.join(data_dir, dir)
    # for each file in the subdirectory
    for filename in (os.listdir(subdir)):
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir, filename)        
        # open the text file
        with open(filepath, "r", encoding="latin-1") as file:
            text = file.read()
```

As far as I can tell, the problem seems to begin when defining the path for the subdirectory, as it now only lists the first subdirectory and the forst text in this.

Comment: Note that your line `for dir in (os.listdir(data_dir)):` will iterate over directories *and* files in that folder. For any file assigned to subdir, the subsequent `os.listdir(subdir)` will then fail.

Comment: Sounds like a task for [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

Answer (score 1):

try a recursive approach like in this pseudo code:

```
def loop_over_folder(folder):
    for item in os.listdir(folder):
        if item is a folder:
            loop_over_folder(item)
        else:
            check_and_manipulate_your_file(item)
```

note that the function loop_over_folder() calls itself as long as it finds subfolders.